# Ansible find module with newermt option

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to fetch all the files that are generated after say 12:00 AM on a specific directory. Tried using find module of ansible but the problem is it accepts only age.

```yaml
- find:
    age: <mins/hrs/days>
```

I need an option to fetch based on timestamp.

`find` module has an option of `-newerXY`. Is there a way in ansible find module to fetch the files that are last modified based on timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *Fetch all the files that are **generated** after say 12:00 AM*

Use `age_stamp: ctime` to count the `age` since the creation of the files. For example

```yaml
- find:
    path: /specific-directory
    age: age_of_the_files
    age_stamp: ctime
```

---

> Q: *Is there a way in ansible find module to fetch the files that are last **modified** based on timestamp?*

A: Use `age_stamp: mtime` to count the `age` since the last modification.

---

Set `age` today noon in seconds. For example

```yaml
    - command: 'date -d 12:00 +%s'
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        age: "{{ result.stdout ~ 's' }}"
```